# Free period penalty in Optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

In my optaplanner ***Course-Curriculum***-like project I want to penalize teacher free periods using ***constraints-streams***. Can anyone give me a hint on how to implement this?

A free period would be a timeslot where no course is scheduled with timeslots before and after where courses are scheduled. Example (free periods in Timeslot 1 and 2):

```
Timetable of a Teacher:  
    Period | Grade | Subject
         0 | 9a    | Math
         1 | ----
         2 | ----
         3 | 10c   | Math
```

I have a constraint that penalizes late lessons which reduces free periods for students but not for teacher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `ifExists()` and `ifNotExists()` in ConstraintStreams. Use at least optaplanner 7.36.